# Chrome tab crashes after rendering works for a few minutes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I am making a 2d game using html5. I am rendering using a buffer and putImageData. Everything renders fine, for a few minutes. There is no problem with the frame rate and nothing pops up in the console.

When I say the tab crashes, I am talking about an "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage." The javascript console says "DevTools was disconnected from the page. Once the page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect." Chrome does not mention any details about what is going wrong.

If need be, I can link a copy of the source. I don't feel that it matters because this has been happening with many canvas projects of mine. The only thing that is similar between these projects is that I use the canvas 2d context and requestAnimationFrame.

**— *EDIT* —**

I found a work-around. Using `document.hidden`, I can decide to only render if the page is visible.

Comment: do you have similar problems with other browsers? you might want to check your app for memory leaks

Comment: you might find this useful in order to detect gpu-memory leaks:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings

Comment: `.getImageData with .putImageData` is memory intensive and probably should not be done inside an animation loop. Have you checked your memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around. Using `document.hidden`, I can decide to only render if the page is visible.